# How to find the css, color codes and other coding a site uses

Tags: html, css

How is it possible to find the css, color codes and other coding (width, height) a site uses for its buttons, backgrounds, text and other things?

What I'm trying to do here, is re-create the side buttons and search box and page width and background found on youtube.com. Is there an easy way to get the code youtube uses for these things? Is there a program or widget that'll let you do it? I've gone mad trying.

Thanks,
Norman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Developer Tools

If you are using Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE8+ they come with **Developer Tools** and HTML/CSS Inspector option.

## Firebug

If you use Firefox, you can go with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/):

- Inspect HTML and modify style and layout in real-time
- Use the most advanced JavaScript debugger available for any browser
- Accurately analyze network usage and performance
- Extend Firebug and add features to make Firebug even more powerful
- Get the information you need to get it done with Firebug.

## Web Developer

You can also go for [Web Developr](http://chrispederick.com/) addon which works in Chrome as well as Firefox

> The Web Developer extension adds various web developer tools to a
> browser. The extension is available for Firefox and Chrome, and will
> run on any platform that these browsers support including Windows, OS
> X and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Chrome/Firefox/Firebug: Right click -> Inspect elements. Profit? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Mozilla Firefox** and add **Addons like colorpicker,Firebug** etc
Or with **Chrome** right-click on the webpage you want to view and **click inspectelement**.
The best i suggest is to use firefox,firefox has tons of addons that helps developers to prevent scratching their head all the time and they are way more flexible then other browsers.
First go and explore the firefox addon website.